# The actress says something like "Even heeeevy" but the subtitle says "Even though ........" Is she really pronuncing ".....though" or is it my ears?

Tags: idiomatic-language, pronunciation, spoken-english, parts-of-speech, listening

This is from the famous TV series "Friends", in which Rachel goes to a job interview a second time. ( see 1:24-2:00 )
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PgyARtIWSw

At 1:49, she suddenly shouts at man and says something like **"Even heeeevy I kissed you,** ....".

I could not understand what she said and listened the same part many times, probably 20 times. It did not sound like anything, so I checked the subtitles and the subtitles say **"Even though I kissed you, ...."** but it does not sound like that at all. I listened again and again, no it does not.

I started to doubt if my ears can hear well and this drives me crazy. Why can't I understand it or are you the natives not able to understand it either, because she says it in a shouting mode. Is this normal or is there something wrong with my hearing? This is what I wonder.

Comment: She says (hesitatingly) 'and e-e-e-ven though I kissed you'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, So do you think is it because I can't hear well or pick well what is being said or is it because she did not pronounce it properly? I mean would you have been able to pick that she was shouting "even though", if you had listened it for the first time?

Comment: I did pick it up the first time. Native speakers understand when people stammer or hesitate.